# How to print input text field in-front drop-down list?

Tags: jquery, html

How to print drop-down list and input for text and date-range 
on same line in this code drop-down list and input field is different line but i want to same line mean input field in-front of drop-down list

please help me i am new in jQuery

```js
function showinput() {
  var value = $("#S1value").val();
  var txt= value.replace(/\_/g, " ");
  var label = $("<label />").attr("for", value).html(txt + ": ");
  switch (value) {
    case "Application_Date":
      var input = $("<input />").attr("type", "text").attr("name", value);
      var input2 = $("<input />").attr("type", "text").attr("name", value + "_2");
      label.append("From: ")
      label.append(input);
      label.append(" To: ");
      label.append(input2);
      $('#beforeSelect').html('').append(label);
      break;
  default:

      var input = $("<input />").attr("type", "text").attr("id", value);
      label.append(input);

 }
  $('#beforeSelect').html('').append(label);
  
}

$("#S1value").on("change", function() {
   showinput();
  
});
 showinput();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="S1value" name="S1value">
<option value="Claim"  >Claim - C</option>
<option value="Title"  >Title - T</option>
<option value="Description"  >Description - D</option>
<option value="Abstract" >Abstract - A</option>
<option value="Application_No"  >Application_Number - APN</option>
<option value="Priority_Number"  >Priority_Number - PN</option>
<option value="Record_Number"  >Record_Number - RN</option>
<option value="Priority_Date" >Priority_Date - PD</option>
<option value="Application_Date"  >Application_Date - APD</option>
<option value="Publication_Date"  >Publication_Date - PD</option>
<option value="US_Class" >US_Class - USC</option>
<option value="IPC_Class"  >IPC_Class - IPC</option>
<option value="CPC_Class"  >CPC_Class - CPC</option>
<option value="Priority_Country_Code"  >Priority Country Code - PCC</option>
<option value="Designate_States"  >Designate_States - DS</option>
<option value="Legal_Status_Current"  >Legal_Status_Current - LSC</option>
</select>

<div id="beforeSelect"></div>
```

Comment: Except for the reuse of html from another post, what have you tried so far yourself to make this work? please show us

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve, I can't find any date-range in your html and you haven't shown any attempt on creating it yourself, Please show us what you expect as the result.

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <select id="S1value" name="S1value">
    <option value="Claim"  >Claim - C</option>
    <option value="Title"  >Title - T</option>
    <option value="Description"  >Description - D</option>
    <option value="Abstract" >Abstract - A</option>
    <option value="Application_No"  >Application_Number - APN</option>
    <option value="Priority_Number"  >Priority_Number - PN</option>
    <option value="Record_Number"  >Record_Number - RN</option>
    <option value="Priority_Date" >Priority_Date - PD</option>
    <option value="Application_Date"  >Application_Date - APD</option>
    <option value="Publication_Date"  >Publication_Date - PD</option>
    <option value="US_Class" >US_Class - USC</option>
    <option value="IPC_Class"  >IPC_Class - IPC</option>
    <option value="CPC_Class"  >CPC_Class - CPC</option>
    <option value="Priority_Country_Code"  >Priority Country Code - PCC</option>
    <option value="Designate_States"  >Designate_States - DS</option>
    <option value="Legal_Status_Current"  >Legal_Status_Current - LSC</option>
    </select>
    
    <div id="beforeSelect">
    <span id="levelinp"></span>: <input type="text" id="Application_No">
    </div>
    
    <script>
    $("#S1value").on("change", function() {
       showinput();
      
    });
    function showinput() {
      var level = $("#S1value").val();
      $('#levelinp').html(level);
    }
    showinput();
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for help but it is not printing same line ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var newEl = $("<input>");
 newEl.name = $("#S1value");
 $("body").append(newEl);
 $("div").text($("#S1value").val()+":");
$("#S1value").on("change",function(){

$("#beforeSelect").text($(this).val()+":");

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="S1value" name="S1value">
<option value="Claim"  >Claim - C</option>
<option value="Title"  >Title - T</option>
<option value="Description"  >Description - D</option>
<option value="Abstract" >Abstract - A</option>
<option value="Application_No"  >Application_Number - APN</option>
<option value="Priority_Number"  >Priority_Number - PN</option>
<option value="Record_Number"  >Record_Number - RN</option>
<option value="Priority_Date" >Priority_Date - PD</option>
<option value="Application_Date"  >Application_Date - APD</option>
<option value="Publication_Date"  >Publication_Date - PD</option>
<option value="US_Class" >US_Class - USC</option>
<option value="IPC_Class"  >IPC_Class - IPC</option>
<option value="CPC_Class"  >CPC_Class - CPC</option>
<option value="Priority_Country_Code"  >Priority Country Code - PCC</option>
<option value="Designate_States"  >Designate_States - DS</option>
<option value="Legal_Status_Current"  >Legal_Status_Current - LSC</option>
</select>

<div id="beforeSelect"></div>
```

Comment: See me question Run code snippet for text and date , I want to same but only one line mean in-front drop-down list,  not in next line